# Background Image doesn't appear in a <span> element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styles

I am trying to display a smiley icon in a `span` tag which is embedded in an list item. Here is the code:

```js
          <p>
            It consists of several tabs:{" "}
            <li>
              Home - Showcase and brief info about what this web site pretends
              to be{" "}
              <span
                style={{
                  padding: "25px",
                  display: "inline-block",
                  background: 'url("smile.png")',
                  height: "17px",
                  width: "50px"
                }}
              >
                {"ss"}
              </span>
            </li>
          </p>
```

This is what i get

[image]

and this is `smile.png`

[image]

Comment: Probably wrong path, use Console debug. Why not using emoji instead?

Comment: It is in the same folder as the jsx file itslf. The name of the image is copy paste

Comment: Side note, <li> in <p> is invalid html.

Comment: @Stickers You were right, the path is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This : Hope This Will Work

```
 <p>
    It consists of several tabs:{" "}
    <li>
      Home - Showcase and brief info about what this web site pretends
      to be{" "}
      <span style="padding: 25px; display: inline-block; height: 17px; width: 50px;">
      <img src="smile.png"></img>
        {"ss"}
      </span>
    </li>
  </p>
```

Comment: I think it can not find the image. the àlt`attribute text is fired

Comment: F*ck! Wrong path! React deosn't care relative paths. I had to give path to the static files directory served by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All. I miss led you. I thought that the React processes relative paths to images too, as it does for component files. It obviously doesn't. I had to give path relative to the `Public` directory where the SERVER serves static files. My mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below versions of adding background image

```
    Import smileImage from “./smile.png”;
    <span
            style={{
              padding: "25px",
              display: "inline-block",
              backgroundImage: "url(" + smileImage + ")",
              height: "17px",
              width: "50px"
            }}
          >
            {"ss"}
          </span>
```

You can also use ES6 string templates as below to achieve the same effect:

```
    backgroundImage: `url(${smileImage})`
```